# sum as comma separated on MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sum, summary

I have a MySQL view which has "sum" and "group by" functions. It's getting total price for each customer by customer name, I want to make this to sum for pieces that ordered, not as different numeric columns but as comma separated text data on single cell.

Comment: can you provide some clear information like table structure ..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CONCAT(SUM(COLA), ', ', SUM(COLB), ', ', ...)`